# Should windows path be in all caps or normal case?

Tags: windows-7, path

Folks, I've been having problems with installing updates to visual studio on windows 7 and traced it to the fact that my %PATH% environment variable is too long.

So I checked what was on the path and it seems that some of the path is in all caps, some in normal case, and a section of the all caps is repeated in normal mixed case as the directory names actually appear on the system, e.g.:

> C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;

Can I safely delete one? Which one?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows uses non case-sensitive file system (NTFS) thus it doesn't matter which way you refer to its files.